# Set wildcard mask for ping

Tags: ping

Is there a way to do a command like `ping 10.0.0.0 0.255.255.255` (wildcard masks), without installing a program, or a similar way to ping every node within a specific network/subnet?

I see something like `ping -b` for broadcast pings, but it does not seem to work (possibly because router does not accept this, but I am unsure).

Comment: You are looking for nmap.

Comment: @Braiam I have used nmap before (I just wanted plain command, no download)

Comment: it is worth noting that `ping` doesn't guarantee host-discovery, because hosts may ignore ping requests. `nmap` is a much more reliable method, and is available for installation via `apt` - it may even already be installed on the system you're using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ping` won't glob netmasks or wildcards.

You can flood ping the broadcast address of a subnet and monitor replies, though many routers will refuse to route ICMP over broadcast, [because this is generally seens as abusive traffic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smurf_attack). Additionally, only root can floodping with a zero interval.

For example:

```
ping -fb <BROADCAST ADDRESS>
```

Instead, you really ought to use [NMAP](http://www.nmap.org/) in a friendly way.

**ETA:** if what you want is a list of node replies, we can get a little more clever:

```
ping -b -c 2 -i 20 <BROADCAST ADDRESS>
```

Where `-b` permits pinging a broadcast address, `-c 2` tells ping to send two pings, `-i 20` tells ping to wait twenty seconds between them.

What this gets you is a near-instant list of replies with a twenty-second wait before termination, followed by traffic statistics. The reason to make two ping echo requests is because if you set `-c 1`, ping will terminate on the very first response that it receives. We set twenty seconds between the two so that the list of replies is somewhat readable. It's a hack, but it works.

From here, you could suppress statistics output by piping to `head -n-4` and then do useful `awk` tricks, `sort`, `uniq` and the like to build a useful one-liner report.

Comment: The flood seemed good, I had to add interval (200 MS at minimum), so I changed your command to `ping -fb -i 1 <Address>`

Comment: I added a better, non-flood example. If you pipe it through a pager like `less` or `more` or redirect the output to a file, it'll make a fairly decent report of replies on a subnet.